# Office365 Home edition with GraphAPI returns invalid_grant error

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

Everyone,

I did a little django app using the freshly release Graph API v1.0.
I use oauth2 protocol to get the token, refresh token. It works all fine
when i use different Office365 developer accounts, but i got a return of someone using his Office365 Home edition and he simply can't get authorized.

He got the following error message:

```
{u'correlation_id': u'9e1b1368-e240-4299-9411-f1780ad977e6',
 u'error': u'invalid_grant',
 u'error_codes': [65001],
 u'error_description': u"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not     consented to use the application with ID '1db510e8-7ef3-4f8d-9c8b-e6c41015cf34'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID:     09085256-de74-448b-b481-4d0c4136d115\r\nCorrelation ID: 9e1b1368-e240-4299-9411-    f1780ad977e6\r\nTimestamp: 2016-01-26 11:42:34Z",
 u'timestamp': u'2016-01-26 11:42:34Z',
 u'trace_id': u'09085256-de74-448b-b481-4d0c4136d115'}
```

Is it because only Developer and business account of office365 can use the Graph API?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you develop an single tenant app or multiple tenant app?

If you want the app also works for the users on the other tenant on the Azure AD, you need to enable the Multi-Tenant or it must be registered in others company’s directory.

And some type of app may require an administrator of the organization to give consent. More detail refer to link below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/

Comment: Hi @fei, thanks for your answer, my app is multi-tenant, but i will take a look at this administrator things, because with any dev account, it didnt created me any problem, only homes ones are failing

Answer (score 0):

Any user within an office 365 tenant can access graph api and based on the granted permissions. you can test out your queries by using the test console tool to make sure you build up your requests properly. The link for the sandbox console tool:

[https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com](http://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com)

If you are using Microsoft Graph Api, i recommend you use this tool:

https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net

Hope this helps you.